# Github action know the name of the latest release of a project

Tags: github, build, yaml, github-actions, release

Is there a way to know the latest release of a certain project?

For example, if the latest release of a certain project is `v0.0.12` I have to make it become `v0.0.13` in order to be able to release a new version when there have been changes.

Here is the code I am using for the release:

```yaml
on:
  push:

name: Build  
jobs:
  build-android:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install npm dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build Android Release
        run: cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
      - name: Upload Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: app-release.apk
          path: android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/
      - name: Create Github Release
        uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
        with:
          artifacts: "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk"
          tag: v0.0.0
          replacesArtifacts: false
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          allowUpdates: true
```

Where it says `tag: v0.0.0` I have to put the name of the next version.

Can you give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

A Git solution (can be used in a `run` step, probably requires non-shallow checkout):

```bash
git tag --list --sort='-version:refname' 'v*' | head -n1
```

Or a GitHub CLI approach, also for a `run` step:

```bash
gh release view --json tagName --jq '.tagName'
```

Both of these return the latest release. To increment it, assign to a variable, split on period, and increment the desired level (patch, in your case):

```bash
tag=$(gh release view --json tagName --jq '.tagName')
IFS=. read -r major minor patch <<< "$tag"
newtag=$major.$minor.$((++patch))
```

And this can be set as an output and used in other steps:

```yaml
      - name: Set new tag
        id: newtag
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          tag=$(gh release view --json tagName --jq '.tagName')
          IFS=. read -r major minor patch <<< "$tag"
          echo "newtag=$major.$minor.$((++patch))" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

      - name: Create Github Release
        uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
        with:
          artifacts: "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk"
          tag: ${{ steps.newtag.outputs.newtag }}
          replacesArtifacts: false
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          allowUpdates: true
```

Comment: This action (https://github.com/christian-draeger/increment-semantic-version) could be helpful to increment version. It also provides granularity at fragment level e.g. major, minor, patch, etc. However, it's a docker action, only applicable to Linux workflows, should work for the OP's use case i.e. `ubuntu-latest`.

Comment: @ben: Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Comment: @Paul That's kind of hard to diagnose without seeing the actual logs.